# Getting OIDC client to load an angular 6 component

Tags: javascript, angular, openid-connect

We're using the OIDC client to authenticate against an Azure host, but would like post_logout handler to load and angular component. Is this possible using this js based library? I've not tried anything yet, I wanted find out if anyone would any idea on how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: You can by set the post_logout_redirect_uri to url of angular component

Comment: Thanks, that works.

Comment: then please mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can by set the post_logout_redirect_uri to url of angular component